# How do I get the cookie consent script to work?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cookieconsent

I have implemented a cookie consent script by Creare:
https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/js/js-eu-cookie-law-banner

in my website:
https://www.drive-tastic.co.uk/

but I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please consider reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Your question lacks any of the relevant details we need to help. We should not have to visit an external website to see your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body tag of your website has an `onload` handler:

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/fb-icon-hover.png')">
```

The cookie script you've downloaded also has an `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(checkCookie(window.cookieName) != window.cookieValue){
        createDiv(); 
    }
}
```

Try replacing it with the following instead:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if(checkCookie(window.cookieName) != window.cookieValue){
        createDiv(); 
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant - that was the cause of problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK it works for that website. but now I have another website that I have installed the same script on: http://www.azltd.co.uk/
and the same problem persists even after replacing the onload handler with the script you gave me